# IE height smaller than Firefox's height

Tags: html, css, height

I'm having some CSS trouble when trying to get IE's display the same as Firefox's display.
Particularly, I'm trying to vertically center text within a box while still having full height:

Shown here:
http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/4045/goddammitv.png

Is there anyway which I can get the height of the link to be the same as the background while still being vertically center (in both IE and Firefox)?

CSS:

```
#buttons
{
    /* RAEG */
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%; 
    text-align: left;
}

ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;  
    position:relative;
    left: 50%;
}

.lbutton
{
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center; 
}
.lbutton a
{
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 85px;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-shadow: #6374AB 1px 0px 5px;
    padding-top: 65px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="buttons">
<ul>
    <li class="orange lbutton"><a href="">projects</a></li>
    <li class="orange lbutton"><a href="">test</a></li>
    <li class="orange lbutton"><a href="">test2</a></li>
</ul>
```

PS: the black border is just for debugging ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a different approach using `line-height`. If you're always going to have a single line word, use a fixed line-height with **equal** top/bottom padding.

Example use

```
a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I try and refrain from using fixed widths/heights, and only specify them when I need to **ensure** that the height will always be fixed. I usually set this to the value of the line-height.

**An element's height is calculated using**

```
line-height + padding
```

So an element with 12px font-size/line-height and 50px top/bottom padding would produce

```
12px + 50px + 50px = 112px
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. For some odd reason, it never crossed my mind to use padding on the bottom without height (d'oh!)